# statistics basic question on covariance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, contest-math, statistical-inference, covariance

anyone would help me in a basic example?

a fair coin is tossed, n times. X is the number of Head and Y is the number of Tails. what is the COV(X,Y).

Comment: Maybe knowing $y =n-x$ will be of use to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
X+Y = n
$$
therefore 
$$
E(Y) = E(n) - E(X) = n - E(x)
$$
now we have
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = E\left[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))\right] 
$$

but we know that
$$
Y-E(Y) = n-X - \left(n-E(x)\right)= -X + E(X) = -(X-E(X))
$$
thus
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = E\left[(X-E(X))\cdot -(X-E(X))\right] = -E\left[(X-E(X))^2\right] = -\mathrm{Var}(X) = -np(1-p)
$$
so you are right with $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = -\dfrac{n}{4}$